# Flutter lost connection to physical device

Tags: flutter, debugging, dart, adb

My physical device gets always disconnected when using flutter debug. I tried to stop and start adb server, delete the remaining app from the phone, run flutter clean, flutter upgrade (is currently on stable 1.17.5) and uncheck/check the debug settings on the phone. Before today everything worked fine and on an emulator it is still working fine.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Redmi 5A in debug mode...
√ Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
Error: ADB exited with exit code -1
Performing Push Install
adb: error: failed to get feature set: device 'd526d3aa7ce5' not found
Error launching application on Redmi 5A.
Exited (sigterm)
```

Flutter Doctor:

```
   [√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.959], locale de-CH)
    [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.0-rc2)
    [√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    [√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.47.3)
    [√] Connected device (2 available)
```

Comment: I have updated my answer, this happened to me today, while debugging on my redmi 5.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Probably a bad USB cable since ADB over WiFi works perfectly.

Comment: This problem is happening with all cables, new and old.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the USB debugging settings, go to developer options then USB debugging, and there, you will find some options, turn them on.

Comment: No, i have turned them on for weeks and thus was able to use the phone before yesterday. I switched now to wifi connection via IP:port and everything works fine.